# If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, is $f|A\to B$ also continuous under the subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology

Say we have a continuous function $f:X\to Y$. Let $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$. Is $f|A\to B$ continuous under the subspace topology for every such subspaces of the domain and range?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, think about the definition of the open sets of $A$ and $B$ and try to prove the continuity of the restriction using the definition with open sets.

Comment: @Quimey- Yes, I thought the same. Was just confirming.

Comment: Also, you can use the universal property: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161461/a-universal-property-for-the-subspace-topology.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by means of diagrams, making extensive use of universal properties whenever possible.

If $f'$ denotes the restriction of $f$ as a map $A\to B$, and $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ and $j:B\hookrightarrow Y$ are the inclusion mappings, then $f'$ is continuous if and only if $jf'$ is continuous. This follows from the universal property of the initial topology, and the subspace topology on $B$ is the initial topology with respect to $j$. Now $jf'$ is the same as $fi$ which is a composition of continuous maps, thus continuous.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\ A & \xrightarrow{i} & X\\
f'\downarrow & & \ \downarrow f\\
\ B & \xrightarrow{j} & Y
\end{array}$$